# General rule of thumb for cts:similar-query - max-terms

Tags: marklogic

I haven’t experimented with cts:similar-query before and it seems that using different numbers in the max-terms option greatly affects the results.

I’ve not changed any of the options for DB settings, so I’m using the default DB settings.

I notice that the default is 16 for max-terms.
I’ve used the cts:distinctive-terms to try to get a feel for what cts:similar-query will use when I change the number of max-terms.

I originally thought that I’d simply take the number of terms (i.e., tokenize on space) in the $node, then I thought maybe I should double that to take into account the pairs of terms.

Is there any “rule of thumb” here?  (BTW, I’m doing this with 3 different DBs, for which the fragment counts are 24M, 131M and 287M, so I have plenty of fragments for similar-query to work on…)

A second question is with regards to cts:distinctive-terms output – what does an empty cts:term mean?

```
<cts:term id="4083217226504034818" val="504" score="1032192" confidence="0.453548" fitness="0" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts"></cts:term>
```

It’d be nice to know what this “term” is since it’s the highest scoring term in the list…

Answer (score 3):

`cts:similar-query` functions like an OR query. The higher the value you configure for `max-terms`, the more matches you are likely to get. If you are only ever taking the top few results, then more terms will probably increase the accuracy of those results. If false positives matter to your use case, then more terms will add more noise to the tail of the result set.

Generally, the terms and results for `cts:similar-query` are highly relative - to the content in your database and to the nodes you give to the function - so it's very hard to come up with a rule for it. To control for false positives, I had better results generating my own query from `cts:distinctive-terms`. To get fewer, more relevant results, you could also try passing a configuration that only returns word pairs. Ultimately, I think you will need to experiment to see what works well for your use case and data set.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the option `details` to `true`, you'll get some information about what the terms mean.

Comment: [1.0-ml] XDMP-INVOPTNAM: cts:distinctive-terms(<text>When reviewing a motion to dismiss, the court must accept all...</text>, <options xmlns:db="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database" xmlns="cts:distinctive-terms">...</options>) -- Invalid option name: /*:options/*:details

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was thinking of a different API. `cts:distinctive-terms` already gives you that information.

Comment: That still gets me back to my question - what does an empty cts:term mean in the distinctive-terms output?  (like my example)